# RasterTek Drawing 2D Directx11 - I am having trouble With i think it is the Zbuffer

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I am having trouble with the Z buffer, when i implement the 2D texture tut from rastertek, i get the image being drawn but when i navaigate the camera past a certain z pos, the 2D texture just do not show.

here is my code for the depthstencil

```
D3DXMatrixOrthoLH(&m_orthoMatrix, (float)screenWidth, (float)screenHeight, screenNear, screenDepth);

    // Clear the second depth stencil state before setting the parameters.
    ZeroMemory(&depthDisabledStencilDesc, sizeof(depthDisabledStencilDesc));

    // Now create a second depth stencil state which turns off the Z buffer for 2D rendering.  The only difference is 
    // that DepthEnable is set to false, all other parameters are the same as the other depth stencil state.
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.DepthEnable = false;
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    depthDisabledStencilDesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
```

heres the code for the zBuffer

```
void D3DClass::TurnZBufferOn()
{
    m_deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_depthStencilState, 1);
    return;
}


void D3DClass::TurnZBufferOff()
{
    m_deviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(m_depthDisabledStencilState, 1);
    return;
}
```

I have been stuck on for soo long please help!!!

Comment: Your code disables the depth buffer so presumably it's not preventing your texture from being drawn. My guess your problem is that your navigating the viewport so that it no longer contains the texture.

Comment: Thank you SOOOOO much dude for pointing me in the right place i found it, I was moving the viewMaxtix and as you said it no long contained the texture, so i set it to the basematrix, and it is fix ty